# Trying to make jQuery remove buttons. It isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make sure jQuery is loaded. I'm trying to test it by setting it up so that when you click on a button, that button is removed. It's not working. Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here?

In addition, I'm trying to center the buttons. The css I'm using flat out doesn't work. I'm sure I could figure that part out on my own with a little effort, but it'd be nice if someone could explain how to.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chaos.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Chaos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>MTG Chaos Roller</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Roll Chaos">
        <input type="submit" value="Roll EnchantWorldLand">
        <input type="submit" value="Roll PersonaLand">
        <input type="submit" value="Roll WackyLand">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black
};

#buttons {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
};
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#buttons).click(function(){

    });

    $(document).on(function('click', '#buttons', .remove(this)){

    });
});
```

Oh, also: Is there a way to keep the formatting of code on this site without having to add four spaces to the beginning of every line? The instructions don't quite explain it.

Comment: Where have you seen such jQuery syntax? I recommend reading http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong

```
    $(#buttons).click(function(){

    });
```

Right:-

```
$('#buttons').click(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        });
```

Wrong

```
 $(document).on(function('click', '#buttons', .remove(this)){

    });
```

Right

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttons', function(){
        $(this).remove();
})
```

Event delegation using `on` is meant mostly for dynamically created elements so that event is attached to the `document head` or any container so that it is delageted to the target element presetn now or added dynamically added in future. Do not use it if you know if it already exist on DOM and does not change or not added dynamically over later period in time. Your first option will work great.

Probably you meant this:-

```
$('#buttons input').click(function () {
      $(this).remove();
});
```

#### Update

You need to load jquery first before your JS(assuming your js uses jquery)

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chaos.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Chaos.js"></script>

    <title>MTG Chaos Roller</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Grah. It's almost there, I can feel it. I removed the `on` bit, and fixed up the `.click` bit to be the same as yours. (just to be clear, I had left that as a bit of useless code that I was going to add stuff to later. It still doesn't work, though. The buttons remain after clicking, even with the fixed code.

Comment: What are you trying to click? Buttons is a div not a button. You wont be able to see it?

Comment: I'm trying to have it apply to the actual submit inputs inside the buttons div. I appear to be going about it in entirely the wrong manner.

Comment: @Sharpevil Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SMc2S/

Comment: @Sharpevil  i See then you try this http://jsfiddle.net/DbCgn/

Comment: Hm. That code works in the fiddle, but not in my page. Are you sure I'm calling jquery correctly? I'm using 4 seperate files. The HTML, the CSS, the JS, and the JS I downloaded from the Jquery site. (The first three I have shown in my question.)

Comment: Load jquery first then your js

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it:

```
$(document).on('click', '#buttons', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

And in your first call, your forgot the quotes:

```
$("#buttons").click(function(){
```